# Applying MVVM to ASP.NET MVC. How to do property mapping?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, mvvm, mapping

There are a lot of articles about using MVVM patterm for ASP .NET MVC. For example, it is http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/helpercoil/archive/2010/08/28/asp-net-mvc-and-the-mvvm-pattern.aspx.

There is only one question for me. We have a lot of ViewModels for one Model. How can I fill Model properties automatic by using viewModel object? How to make automatic property mapping?

I use Entity Framework.

For example, I have model Test with the following properties:

- id
- name
- title
- idUser
- idCompany

I made ViewModel for my task. This ViewModel (TestUserViewModel) uses for simple user with the following properies:
 - id
 - name
 - title

For example, user edit an existing test. As the result, we have an object with type TestUserViewModel. I want:

- synchronize Model object and ViewModel.
- save the default valies for idCompany, idUser - for properties, which were excluded from current ViewModel.
- use some automatic stuff - it may be something like ApplyCurrentValues. I really don't want to write a lot of following code:

  ```
  modelObj.name=viewModelObj.name;
  modelObj.title=viewModelObj.title;
  ```

Using System.Reflexion for this looks like bad, too.

So, how to do it?

Comment: MVVM is not a good pattern for ASP.NET MVC, where MVC is a better pattern.

Comment: Did you read that blog post?  It was a tragedy.  CSS in the webpage, half the code samples were line-numbered, half were not...  I wouldn't take any advice from someone who can't be bothered to spend five minutes cleaning up their work.

Comment: Yes, that post was bad for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to write a lot of mapping code from one object to another you might want to look into mapping tools like AutoMapper http://automapper.org/

Having said that, as @Darin Dimitrov pointed out, you should review your architecture too. If you are doing ASP.NET MVC you should become more familiar with MVC rather than MVVM. As you read more about how to use MVC you are going to start seeing the use of "viewModels". Keep in mind that these "viewModels" in MVC have nothing to do with "VM" in "MVVM".

Comment: Yes, as I understood, it is only terminology problem. It names MVVM here - http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/helpercoil/archive/2010/08/28/asp-net-mvc-and-the-mvvm-pattern.aspx. Maybe, it is not correct name.

Comment: Indeed, I think the blog post that you referenced got the MVVM and ViewModels concepts wrong. One of the comments on the post (the one by Charles Vallance) points this out. The author of the blog post seems to acknowledge this in a roundabout way but never updated the original blog post. Oh well...